# Reload a source file on multiple processes in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a Julia source file with a simulation function, which I want to run in parallel on multiple processors.

```
addprocs(1)
using Autoreload
arequire("testp.jl")
testresults = pmap(testp,[100,100])    
* change code *    
areload()
testresults = pmap(testp,[100,100])
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#code-availability-and-loading-packages), `include` or `using` do not bring the module content in scope on all processes, so I have to use `require` and to remove the module declaration from the .jl file. I do testing in Jupyter, so I often change the function code in an editor and want to reload the .jl file in Jupyter. Since `reload` function does not work with non-module source files, I have to use an obsolete [Autoreload](https://github.com/malmaud/Autoreload.jl) package with `arequire` and `areload`. It works in the single-process case. However, the function code is not reloaded on either processor with 2 or more processes. I am using Julia 0.4.3 x86_64.

How can I reload the code without restarting the kernel?